# Did you know that Stack Exchange has a blogging platform?

Tags: discussion, blog

That is my way of circuitously floating the idea of a cooking blog!

Here is [Blog Overflow](http://blogoverflow.com/).

Here are a couple of other .SE's blogs. Some are more successful than others!

- [Sci-Fi](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/)
- [English](http://english.blogoverflow.com/)
- [Gaming](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/)
- [Stats](http://stats.blogoverflow.com/)

A few, not particularly organized thoughts:

1. The enthusiasm and interest for a blog needs to come from you all. I am merely suggesting it because I would like to read that potential blog.
2. I think we have a really interesting, engaged and intelligent community here at Seasoned Advice and I think if a blog is an idea you all are interested it would be a freaking awesome blog.
3. What do you guys think? Ask me questions if anything I have written is unclear!

Answer (score 6):

I would totally love to read such a blog! In fact, I suspect that we already have some answers to questions that would be fantastic blog posts. (The process of finding an answer to [Could coconut cream be used to create a non-dairy ganache for whipping?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11793/could-coconut-cream-be-used-to-create-a-non-dairy-ganache-for-whipping) would be my recommendation for a start.)

Other useful topics might be compilations of the best advice members have garnered from the site. (I never thought about using a deglazing technique with water to help prepare frying pans for cleaning until I read it [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6155/what-does-to-deglaze-a-pan-mean).)

In addition, a blog would allow users to share recipes -- the one thing which the community has to constantly work against in the main Seasoned Advice questions. Or even better, an analysis by some others about how they evaluate recipes -- with extended examples from a specific dish. (I tend to read several versions of a recipe from different sources and pick and choose the aspects I like best, but I would be interested to see how others approach the same issue.)

Comment: Excellent points! I also like the recipe thing and different perspectives on the same recipe.

Comment: I don't want to add another answer, so as a comment, I'd be willing to write for the blog. I would be happy to discuss how I evaluate recipes as an initial contribution.

Answer (score 4):

I like the idea. I will definitely read it, and I could imagine contributing to it.

About content: Long before the current swag offer was implemented, we discussed in chat ideas about possible rewards for the highest rep users. Back then, we discussed following: the community deciding on a topic for a volunteer to experiment on, and this person experimenting and describing the results. Such content could become a more or less regular column on the blog. Obviously, the experiments will have to be small scale, but they can still be fun. There were other ideas, still lying somewhere in the transcripts. Maybe they can be transformed into content somehow.

Comment: Cool, sounds awesome. I will see what I can find!

Answer (score 2):

I could probably be convinced to write up something on bread baking, with photos even.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a good idea and cooking provides plenty of opportunity for posts. As already stated, it would also give us an opportunity to explore topics that are "off topic" for the site itself but still be interesting for the user base. I'd be willing to contribute to it.